# Dropdown taxonomy lists in admin menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, themes, admin, taxonomy, admin-menu

I've added 4 taxonomy list to my wordpress backend:

1. BH Job Experience
2. BH Job Types
3. BH Job Regions
4. BH Job Tags

These taxonomy lists are added under **Job Listings** like this:

[image]

Now I would like to have these 4 taxonomy lists under a dropdown with name **BullHorn**. Something like this:

[image]

But I can't really find information about this. Can someone give me a tutorial, or a start, or some keywords I can search on? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately WordPress does not support third-level admin menu, so there's no easy way to achieve the result you want.

You can only remove these 4 submenu items, add a submenu item instead which will be a link to a custom admin page and display these 4 links within that page (content).

Read about following hooks:

- [remove_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page)
- [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)